# Is there a way to get in Python the original value of the parameters of a function given a frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inspection

How to get the values of the call parameters of a function / method?

It's for a debugging tool, and it would be used in a scenario like this one:

```
import inspect

def getCallParameter():
  stack = inspect.stack()
  outer = stack[1] #This is an example, I have a smarter way of finding the right frame
  frame = outer.frame
  print("") #print at least a dict of the value of the parameters, and at best, give also which parameter are passed explicitly (e.g. with f(2, 4) an input of this kind : "a=2, b=4, c=5(default)")


def f(a, b=4, c=5):
  a+=b+c
  getCallParameters()
  return a
```

Note : I'm aware of `inspect.formatargsvalues()` but it doesn't meet my requirements since in the `f(2,4)` example, it would have printed "a=11, b=4, c=5)"

What I though of, would be to watch on the outer frame the values passed. It's not a problem if I don't get the original state of the passed object, as long as I get the objects initially bound to the variable parameters.

Example:

```
# with f(4)

def f(a, b=4, c=[])
  c.append(5)
  getCallParameters() # a=4, b=4, c=[5] is ok even if I would have preferred c=[]
  c = [4]
  getCallParameters() # here, I expect c=[5] or c=[]
```

Comment: Why would you want do this? If you want to save the original values, don't edit them and use new variables.

Comment: This example is to show the requirements, it's not "really" how it would be used (but if it works used like this, that would be enougth for me)

Comment: I realized it is, I am just wondering in which actual case you would actually want to do this. (Genuine interest)

Comment: there are some cases, for example a kind of "post mortem" debugging, when you add the extra debugging overhead only after an exception is caught (note the the builtin traceback doesn't provide such an information, maye because that's not easily done or even impossible)

Comment: I see, this is a rather interesting question ill try and tackle it later, and following either way.

Answer (score 1):

I have a different way in mind to cope with finding exact parameters passed, but I do wonder if it is compatible with your debugging tool. This takes good care of how the function is called. Still, real frame parameters should be retrieved with things like `inspect`.

```
def inspect_decorator(func):            # decorator 
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):       # wrapper function
        # TODO: don't print! consume somewhere else
        print('{} is called with args={} kwargs={}'.format(func.__name__, args, kwargs))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)    # actual execution
    return wrapper                      # wrapped function


@inspect_decorator
def f(a, b=4, c=5):
    a += b + c
    return a


f(3)
f(3, 5)
f(3, b=4)
# f is called with args=(3,) kwargs={}
# f is called with args=(3, 5) kwargs={}
# f is called with args=(3,) kwargs={'b': 4}
```

In the TODO part, you may use a context stack to keep track of every function interested. But again, it depends on what you have done with the whole project.